# Consecutive days on a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've got the following line in a stored procedure when someone is logging into his account:

```
UPDATE AcccountsTable SET LogDate = getdate() WHERE AccID = @identity
```

However, I want to add a new feature where on every consecutive login day to add `+1` to a new column (`ConsecutiveDays`) in my `AccountsTable`.

For example:

```
Day 1: 2018-04-11 20:00
Day 2: 2018-04-12 15:30
Day 3: 2018-04-13 10:20
and etc ....
```

Total consecutive days should be 3 days for the user account id that logged during these consecutive days.

If the user doesn't log on `day 4` - `2018-04-14` but logs on the next day `2018-04-15` then all consecutive days should be reverted back to `1`.

I've searched for a similar solution for a stored procedure on MSSQL Server 2008 R2 but without success. I am not good at SQL at all, so I will appreciate your help a lot! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That shouldn't be too hard using [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql):

```
UPDATE AcccountsTable 
SET ConsecutiveDays = 
    CASE WHEN CAST(LogDate as Date) = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) As Date) 
              AND ConsecutiveDays < 28 THEN 
        ConsecutiveDays + 1 
    WHEN CAST(LogDate as Date) = CAST(GETDATE() as Date) THEN
        ConsecutiveDays 
    ELSE 
        1 
    END,
    ChallengesCompleted = 
    CASE WHEN ConsecutiveDays = 28 
              AND CAST(LogDate as Date) = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) As Date)
    THEN 
         ChallengesCompleted + 1
    ELSE
         ChallengesCompleted
    END,
    LogDate = GETDATE()
WHERE AccID = @identity
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I am going to test it out. However, if the user logs multiple times during a consecutive day, it should add only `+1` value to the `ConsecutiveDays` column and ignore the rest of the logins for this specific day. I am not sure but will the above prevent that? Thank you again!

Comment: Actually, my original answer would set the `ConsecutiveDays` back to 1 if a user logged in twice the same day. I've edited it and added another `when` clause to the case so if the user logged in more than once in the same day, the `ConsecutiveDays` will only increase once and stay that way for the next logins in the same day.

Comment: Awesome, you have no idea how thankful I am for helping me out. Before I accept the answer, can you please help me lastly because I forgot to mention one clause. If the user is logging and has 29 consecutive days it should restart the consecutive days for another row, so the value should be again `1`. Thank you!

Comment: So that user will now have 2 rows in the AcccountsTable?

Comment: If the user logs on his 28 consecutive day then it should update another column called `ChallengesCompleted` and add `+1` value to it. However, on the next day `29` if the user logs again then the `ConsecutiveDays` column instead to be `29` days it should revert back to `1` value because the user already completed the `28 days challenge` and will start a new one. That's really lastly and I will get it fully working as I really wanted in first place. THANK YOU!

Comment: Add another `when` to the case expresstion. I'm currently on my cellphone and cam't update the answer.

Comment: I will try to do it myself but I am not sure if I will succeed. When you've got time please update it, so I won't screw something. Thank you. And also, will this new query really slow down my db performance? I've got a lot of logins per day, so will it cause a drastic change? Thank you a lot for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: @Plar625, the comments section isn't the place to ask follow up questions. You posted a question and Zohar answered it. He even took it to your first level of "oh, and I forgot to ask..." You shouldn't use his code without understanding what it does, so if you take the time to figure that out, you should be able to finish the query yourself. If you need more help, or if you find that you have performance concerns, those should be handled by starting new questions.

Comment: @EricBrandt While correct, my last edit wasn't an `Oh, I forgot this part` kind of edit, it was a bug in my answer I've fixed. (Granted. that "Oh I forgot" was what brought it to my attention), so basically if I edit my answer again, this would be the first edit that will actually be a followup.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please take @EricBrandt's advice and try to really understand what you are using. I've also added a link to the official documentation of `case` in SQL server.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it! I will definitely examine it and make sure I understand it correctly. Just to note, it shouldn't cause a drastic change to the performance, right? I've got a lot of logins per day but still it's a single query, so I believe it should be fine, correct? Also, because the final version of it is a little bit bigger than expected and to avoid any mess in my current stored procedure for logins, I will create an entire new stored procedure called `consecutivedays` and include an execution line in the login stored procedure like that `exec consecutivedays @identity`

Comment: Performance is kinda hard to predict, since it involves many factors. That being said, usually adding a few case expressions to a statement should not effect performance in a noticeable way.

Comment: Awesome! I hope you have a great day. Thanks!

Comment: You too. Glad to help :-)